# How to Inject directive in component with default value? (to avoid NullInjectorError)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I want to have reusable component which works regardless of if its ancestor have customRootDirective or not.
My component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component5',
  templateUrl: './component5.html',
  styleUrls: [ './component5.scss' ],
})
export class Component5 {
  constructor(
    public customRootDirective: CustomRootDirective,
  ) {}
   
  someMethod(){
    console.log(this.customRootDirective.elementRef.nativeElement.innerText);
  }

}
```

Directive usage in some template (here it works):

```
<component1>
  <component2 customRootDirective>
    <component3>
      <component4>
        <component5>
            here I'd like to use reference to component2 and some customRootDirective methods
            but it is possible that ancestors don't have customRootDirective
        </component5>
      </component4>
    </component3>
  </component2>
</component1>
```

Here it gives error:
`NullInjectorError: No provider for CustomRootDirective!`

```
<component1>
  <component2>
    <component3>
      <component4>
        <component5>
            here I don't need reference to ancestors elements
        </component5>
      </component4>
    </component3>
  </component2>
</component1>
```

I have tried with no success:

```
export class Component5 {
  constructor(
    public customRootDirective: CustomRootDirective = null,
  ) {}
```

Please, help, I'm stuck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the [`@Optional`](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional) decorator should be used:

```
export class Component5 {
  constructor(
    @Optional()
    readonly customRootDirective: CustomRootDirective
  ) {}
}
```

If the directive cannot be found, the parameter will have `null` as value